# CURL не учитывает установленные HTTP заголовки

Tags: php, curl

Помогите разобраться с отправкой запроса к API сервису "СкладОблако" через CURL

Вот сам метод с исп. CURL

```
/**
 * CURL
 * @param $response
 * @return array
 */
function curl_get($host, $headers, $method='GET', $fields = array()){
    $ch = curl_init();


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);

    if(count($headers)) { //is HTTP headers
        debug($headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    }

    if($method=='POST') { //is POST
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        if(is_array($fields)) {
            if (count($fields)) {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
            }
        }else{
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
        }
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT,true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT , 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);


    //Info request
    $curl_getinfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
    //if($curl_getinfo['http_code']!=200) {
    //\Bitrix\Main\Diag\Debug::writeToFile('Error - curl_getinfo');
    \Bitrix\Main\Diag\Debug::writeToFile(curl_getinfo($ch));
    //}

    //Error curl request
    if($curl_err = curl_error($ch)) {
        \Bitrix\Main\Diag\Debug::writeToFile($curl_err);
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}
```

В него передаются вот такие заголовки

```
$headers_arr = array(
    'Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
    'Host' => 'cdekff.ddns.net',
    'Content-Length' => $content_length,
    'SOAPAction' => 'http://cowms.ru/outbound/Client_CreateUpdate'
);
```

которые в методе устанавливаются в CURL так

```
if(count($headers)) { //is HTTP headers
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
}
```

Но в распечатке **curl_getinfo($ch)** видно что Content-Type совсем другой! ([content_type] => **text/html** или Content-Type: **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**) почему так происходит, из-за чего игнорируется установка именно этого заголовка?

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://cdekff.ddns.net:40100/OUTBOUND.asmx?op=Client_CreateUpdate
    [content_type] => text/html
    [http_code] => 415
    [header_size] => 225
    [request_size] => 789
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.010619
    [namelookup_time] => 0.004307
    [connect_time] => 0.006409
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.006577
    [size_upload] => 576
    [size_download] => 155
    [speed_download] => 14596
    [speed_upload] => 54242
    [download_content_length] => 155
    [upload_content_length] => 576
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.010589
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 92.242.40.125
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 40100
    [local_ip] => 89.253.230.141
    [local_port] => 36778
    [request_header] => POST /OUTBOUND.asmx?op=Client_CreateUpdate HTTP/1.1
Host: cdekff.ddns.net:40100
Accept: */*
http://cowms.ru/outbound/Client_CreateUpdate
Content-Length: 576
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded


)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ура! Время почитать официальную документацию php https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php! Её авторы хорошо постарались

> CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER: Массив устанавливаемых HTTP-заголовков, в формате array('Content-type: text/plain', 'Content-length: 100')

Обратили внимание на формат? Это массив строк. А что передаёте вы? О нет, ассоциативный массив. Исправьте и будьте внимательны.

Comment: Да спасибо Егор, я уже это нашел хотел удалить пост но раз вы ответили то оставлю!

Comment: @toorr2p спасибо :-)